# Is there any way to write select sql query which will take the value from excel sheet and display the result in sql window

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have one excel sheet(name as:-LTATestData.xls). It contain some column with corresponding some value. I want select sql query which read the column value from excel sheet  and display the result.

I have tried to search in google, i get below query which may solve my purpose

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
            'Excel 10.0;Database=C:\work\LTATestData.xls',
            'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

But when I run this query I am getting below error message:- "OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode."

Please let me know how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main cause for this might be because of a mismatch between a 64-bit SQL Server and a 32-bit Microsoft Office installation. Therefore rather upgrade to a 64-bit Microsoft Office than downgrade a sql server version.

Alternatively, here a couple of posts if your versions are all up to date (**Please read the comments sections as well**)

The following posts might be helpful solving the problem: [HOW TO: FIX ERROR - "the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

AND

[SQL SERVER – Fix: Error: MS Jet OLEDB 4.0 cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is used to run in apartment mode.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/03/sql-server-fix-error-ms-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries-because-the-provider-is-used-to-run-in-apartment-mode/)