# VC# 2017 RC and VC#2008 connection string error

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have been trying to make a simple form to do a minor calculating and connect to database afterwards.

I am using my PC (64bit OS Win 10 Pro). I have both VC# 2008 and VC# 2017 RC.

My first problem is that I can't build or debug my VC#2008 version .sln file on my (64bit OS) PC. I have attached a Screenshot. It says:

> jet.4.0 not registered in your local machine.

My second problem is that I can't seem to add any data from my VC#2017 RC form to the database. It says `connectstate.Open();` unhandled error.

Here is the code snippet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tenant_Bill_Generator
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
  OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'billdata._Billdata' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
   this.billdataTableAdapter.Fill(this.billdata._Billdata);
   billdataBindingSource.DataSource = this.billdata._Billdata;
  }
  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   connect.ConnectionString=@"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;
   Data Source=C:\Users\GCL\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Tenant Bill Generator\Tenant Bill Generator.accdb";
   double con_unit = 0, bill = 0, presr = 0, prevr = 0, fmem = 0; 
   double noso = 0, noda = 0, re_la = 0, mcon_unit = 0, totalbill = 0, perunitcost = 0;
   presr = double.Parse(txtPresentMeterReading.Text);
   prevr = double.Parse(txtPreviousMeterReading.Text);

   con_unit = double.Parse(txtMainConsumedUnit.Text);
   mcon_unit = ((presr) - (prevr));
   lblConsumedUnit.Text = Convert.ToString(mcon_unit);

   if (con_unit < 75)
   {
    bill = con_unit * 3.8;
   }
   else if (con_unit < 200)
   {
    bill = (75 * 3.8) + ((con_unit - 75) * 5.14);
   }
   else if (con_unit < 300)
   {
    bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + ((con_unit - 200) * 5.36);
   }
   else if (con_unit < 400)
   {
    bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + (100 * 5.36) + ((con_unit - 300) * 5.63);
   }
   else if (con_unit < 600)
   {
    bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + (100 * 5.36) + (100 * 5.63) + ((con_unit - 400) * 8.70);
   }
   else if (con_unit < 600)
   {
    bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + (100 * 5.36) + (100 * 5.63) + (200 * 8.70) + (con_unit * 9.98);
   }
   else bill = (75 * 3.8) + (125 * 5.14) + (100 * 5.36) + (100 * 5.63) + (200 * 8.70) + ((con_unit - 600) * 9.98);
   lblTotalBill.Text = Convert.ToString(totalbill);
   string rn = txtRoomno.Text;                     
   string mob = txtMonthofBilling.Text;
   string pmr = txtPresentMeterReading.Text;            
   string rwt = txtMainConsumedUnit.Text;
   string prevmr = txtPreviousMeterReading.Text;
   connect.Open();
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into userdata(Roomno,MonthofBilling,PresentReading,PreviousReading,ConsumedUnit,TotalBill,MainConsumedUnit)" 
                    + "Values(@rn,@mob,@pmr,@rwt,@prevmr,lblConsumedunit.Text,lblTotalBill.Text)", connect);
   if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
   {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@rn", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = rn;                
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mob", OleDbType.Char, 100).Value = mob;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pmr", OleDbType.Char, 100).Value = pmr;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@rwt", OleDbType.Char, 100).Value = rwt;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prevmr", OleDbType.Char, 100).Value = prevmr;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("lblConsumedUnit.Text", OleDbType.Char, 100).Value = lblConsumedUnit.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("lblTotalBill.Text", OleDbType.Char, 100).Value = lblTotalBill.Text;                
    try
    {
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     MessageBox.Show("Data Added To Database");
     txtRoomno.Text = "";
     txtMonthofBilling.Text = "";
     txtPresentMeterReading.Text = "";
     txtPreviousMeterReading.Text = "";
     lblConsumedUnit.Text = "";
     txtMainConsumedUnit.Text = "";
     lblTotalBill.Text = "";                    
     connect.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception expe)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
     connect.Close();
    }
   }
   else
   {
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**Note:** I am unable to find where the connection is left open. I already have used try/catch block.

Comment: `"It says "connectstate.Open();" unhandled error."` - No it doesn't...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This is the error message I am receving(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\GCL\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Tenant Bill Generator\Tenant Bill Generator.accdb'.'
)

Comment: "unhandled error" isn't itself an error message.  It's telling you that there *is* an error, but you're not handling it.  So the only advice at that point is to handle the error.  Usually this can be accomplished with a `try/catch` block.  By handling the error you can determine what the *actual* error is and then take steps to correct it.

Comment: Again Thanks. I have set the connect.Open(); statement before try and catch statement. Should I use the connect.Open(); statement into the try catch statement?

Comment: If it's throwing an exception, and you want to catch that exception, then yes... it should be inside a `try` block with an appropriate `catch`.

Comment: Please never take screenshots of your code, always give SO the text, formatted properly to show up in code blocks.

Comment: Take a look at [this SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684499/is-there-any-way-to-write-select-sql-query-which-will-take-the-value-from-excel/27684651#27684651), see if it will help you out.

Comment: Sorry it is giving me a bunch of build errors now. What should I do now?Should I supply the code pattern I am using???

Comment: Yes @KhandkarAsifHossain, please provide a code snippet

Comment: @KhandkarAsifHossain: `"What should I do now?"` - You should correct those errors.  Note: Nobody here knows what those errors are because you haven't told us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Back with the solution. Thanks for your help guys though.

Actually the my problem was that I was able to build my .sln file using vc#2008. As soon as I found that out I simply changed the 'build on cpu' x86 option and walla worked like a charm.

I then personally researched a lot then I figured that the .sln file I was using was originally created on a 32 bit OS on my other pc. I just copied the file.

Again thanks for your directional comments.